# Finding a Dual Sequence for a Sequence of Polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, inner-products

I am reading a [paper](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0723086907000485/1-s2.0-S0723086907000485-main.pdf?_tid=48ad6e72-0795-11e5-9b15-00000aacb362&acdnat=1433077525_3daf0194f5d0c33a3cc13a3bb2ebc593) on quadratic decomposition of Appell Sequences and would like to see if I can apply it to a particular Appell sequence that I am working with.  However, my undergraduate Linear Algebra course didn't really go hard into linear functionals and inner products as much as I would like, so I'm just trying to get help notationally and get a little push in the right direction. I'm copying the first paragraph here.

Suppose we are looking at $P(\mathbb{C})$, the vector space of polynomials with coefficents in $\mathbb{C}$, and its dual space $P'$.  The elements of $P'$ are called $forms$.  The action of $u\in P'$ on $f\in P$ is denoted as $\langle{u,f}\rangle$.  In particular, we denote by $(u)_n=\langle{u,x^n}\rangle, n\ge 0,$, the moments of $u$.  Recall that a linear operator $T:P\rightarrow P$ has a transpose $T^t:P'\rightarrow P'$ defined by
$$\langle{T^t(u),f}\rangle=\langle{u,T(f)}\rangle, u\in P', f\in P$$
For example, for any form $u$, any polynomial $g$, let $Du=u'$ and $gu$ be the forms defined as usually
$$\langle{u',f}\rangle=-\langle{u,f'}\rangle, \langle{gu,f}\rangle=\langle{u,gf}\rangle$$
where $D$ is the differential operator.  Thus, the differentiation operator $D$ on forms is minus the transpose of the differentiation operator $D$ on polynomials.

I have a sequence of polynomials generated by 
$$\frac{2e^x}{e^{2x}+1+2x}\cdot e^{xz}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty B_n(z)\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
associated with the defined polynomials above.

I understand that, for example, $\langle{u_0,B_0}\rangle=1$ and $\langle{u_0,B_k}\rangle=0$ for $k>0$. If my first few polynomials are $$\{1,z-1, z^2-2z+3,z^3-3z^2+9z-15,...\}$$ how do I use the above information to figure out my dual sequence?

Edit:  I have updated the question to more appropriately convey my issues and I copied the first paragraph from the paper I'm wanting to work with to hopefully get some understanding and apply the concepts to my own Appell Sequence.

Comment: Is that the standard inner product $\int fg dx$?

Comment: The paper itself does not explicitly define the inner product, which was some of my confusion.  I assume since we are working with polynomials / continuous functions that it would be.

Comment: Every possible inner product yields its own dual sequence. If you're in a situation where you don't have the definition of the inner product, it's hard for me to imagine that the dual sequence will be of any use at all.

Comment: @Iceman Do you know how to determine the action of these linear functionals $L(\cdot) = \langle u_n, \cdot\rangle$ on the basis $\{x^k\}$?  That's doable, but without knowing the inner product, I can't think of a nice way to specify the functions $u_n$ themselves.  A great inner product to have would be the one which your polynomials are already orthogonal wrt.  Maybe there is a way to derive that from the generating function of the polys?

Comment: I do not, and actually, I went back and reread the article, and i actually think that the notation I thought was inner product is the action.  I'm going to write the first paragraph of the preliminaries section here, so perhaps you can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll demonstrate how you can calculate some of the moments of $\langle u_0, \cdot \rangle$, i.e. $\langle u_0, x^n \rangle$.  To ease notation, let 
           $$L_0(p) = \langle u_0, p \rangle$$
If we know that $L_0(B_n(x)) = \delta_0(n)$ then 
$$L_0(B_0) = L_0(1) = 1$$
By linearity, $ 0 = L_0(B_1) = L_0(1) - L_0(x) = 1 - L_0(x)$ so
$$L_0(x) = 1$$
Again $0 = L_0(B_2) = L_0(x^2 - 2x + 3) = L_0(x^2) - 2L_0(x) + 3 L_0(1)$ so
$$L_0(x^2) = -1$$
etc.

Comment: So then if I'm looking at $L_1(p)=\langle{u_1,p}\rangle$, that same linearity will hold and we can then look at $L_1(B_0)=0, L_1(B_1)=1,$,...

Comment: @Iceman  Yes.  Originally you had the relationship: $⟨u_n,B_k⟩=\delta_{n,k}$.  That will specify all of them completely.

Comment: Okay.  I think I got it.  Thanks!